# Omitting the verb in non-parallel clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, ellipses, omissibility, clefts, reduced-relative-clauses

I've seen this sentence in a textbook and it sounds unnatural to me.

> It was the Ottomans who were developed and Western Europe underdeveloped.

I feel like the omission might have been correct If the second subject had been *"Western Europeans"*, although that structure also seems unusual to me. But in this instance isn't the omission incorrect since the two clauses are non-parallel. And does it being a cleft sentence have an effect on the correctness of the omission?

Comment: There's an [answer to this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108502/when-is-it-allowable-to-elide-is/108503#108503) from John M. Landsberg  that suggests you need to be consistent and not mix singular and plural, but I'm not sure how general a rule that really is. There are other similar questions here; they may not be easy to find, but you could have a look.

Comment: ...but all I see is "deletion" of "predictably repeated" ***who were***. Nothing unusuall about that, either.

Comment: Your correction helps, but Western Europe *is* a metonym for Western Europeans.

Comment: It's sloppy and inelegant writing, but grammatically acceptable if you can buy: *It was the Ottomans who were developed and Western Europe who were underdeveloped*. (That wouldn't fly in American English.) In your text, a sentence follows your example that *is* incorrect: *English scrap **metal** from old church bells **were** among the items the Ottomans favoured for the purpose of manufacturing arms.* (*were* should be *was*.)

Comment: I'd guess that some members usage panels made up of proficient Anglophones would  consider this sentence 'acceptable' and others 'unacceptable'. My only real gripe is that 'the Ottomans' and 'Western Europe' paired like this implies similar homogeneity.

Comment: Should be "Europeans" if you're gonna have parallelismus. But Whiz-deletion doesn't care normally. When the verb is deleted so is its inflection for tense, number, and person.